# How to change QT (KDE) application icons for gnome?

Tags: gnome, kde, qt, dolphin

I'm running gnome3 on Ubuntu 12.04 and my dolphin looks like this:

[image: Dolphin on gnome-shell]

I really don't like these oxygen themed icons and want to use the Faenza icons.

I tried backing up the oxygen icons and downloading a version of Faenza for KDE and then making a sym link from Faenza to oxygen like:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/icons/Faenza-KDE /usr/share/icons/oxygen
```

but nothing changed??!?!

So where are QT apps pulling their icons from?!?!

Comment: Just installl kde sytem settings, you can configure icons from it

Comment: If you are referring to qt4-qtconfig tool than that does not have icon functions.  Can you give me the name of the package to install? Does it have a GUI interface?

Comment: No it is not qt4-qtconfig, but I forgot the exact package name, just search for system settings in usc, It will appear in the top list

Comment: If this fix doesn't work for you please also see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126870/icon-theme-doesnt-affect-some-qt-applications/297507#297507).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The KDE System Settings changes those Icons: `sudo apt-get install systemsettings` will install it.

From there go to Application Appearance>Icons.

Comment: worked like a champ. thank you. I now have dolphin working perfectly as default fm in ubuntu gnome-shell AAAAAAAAAAAA im a genious.

Comment: Not working in UbuntuStudio 16.04 (I launch systemsettings5 from terminal, open the window but the option are missing)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install all the dependencies and just need to change the icons, you may already have the neccessary component installed:

```
kcmshell4 icons
```

Works great for changing toolbar icons in kde apps.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637051/ubuntu-15-04-change-kde-applications-icons)

EDIT: Unfortunately, for qt5 apps you need kcmshell5, the icons module for that is included in the plasma-desktop package, which has a sh*tload of dependencies... :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Install packages:

   - Fedora 33: `sudo dnf install qt5ct qt5-qtstyleplugins`
   - Ubuntu 20.10: `sudo apt install qt5ct qt5-style-plugins` (untested by author)
2. Edit `/etc/enviroment` to contain a line `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct`
3. Reboot
4. Open “Qt5 settings” („Qt5-Einstellungen“ in German, command `qt5ct`)
5. Configure the appearence as needed
6. Launch your Qt5 application