# Ubuntu 15.04: Change KDE application's icons

Tags: kde, qt, icon-themes

is there a way to change the icon theme that is used by KDE applications like Krusader in Unity? KDE systemsettings don't work any more.

Can't I just edit some file?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

So, I was looking for over an hour befor I decided to post here, and five minutes later I find a question. Well, I guess others can use it. Just launch this in a shell:

```
kcmshell4 icons
```

Comment: This fixed the problem with Krusader icons on 16.04 LTS. Thank you!